# "kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=310" Error in Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire

I want to make http Session using a proxy server  I try free proxy it work fine but when I used proxy with Authentication it not work ! this my code  :

```
  var proxyConfiguration = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
    proxyConfiguration[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy] = "proxy" as AnyObject?
    proxyConfiguration[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort] = 29842 as AnyObject?
    proxyConfiguration[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable] = 1 as AnyObject?
   proxyConfiguration[kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost ] = "proxy" as AnyObject
proxyConfiguration[kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort] = 9292 as AnyObject
   proxyConfiguration[kCFProxyUsernameKey] = "Myusername"  as AnyObject
   proxyConfiguration[kCFProxyPasswordKey] = "Mypassord" as AnyObject
    let cfg = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration
    cfg.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyConfiguration

    let ip = URL(string: "https://api.ipify.org?format=json")

    requestManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: cfg)
    requestManager.request(ip!).response { response in
        print("Request: \(response.request)")
        print("Response: \(response.response)")
        print("Error: \(response.error)")

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
        }
    }
```